# google-spread-sheetのグラフで24:00:00以上の数値を表示させたい。

Tags: google-spreadsheet

google spread sheetを使用してて、仕事の合計時間からグラフを作成しています。
そこでなんですが、24:00:00以上を超える数値をグラフに現すと、

例:26:00:00→2:00:00として扱われる。
　 28:16:00→4:16:00として扱われる。

どうにか24時間以上の数値を表示させたいのですが、方法はありますか？
どうかご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

24時間を超える時間を、00:00:00～24:00:00の範囲で表現することは不可能です。

単純な対処方法として、時間を日単位の実数で扱うというものがあります。
時、分、秒が、それぞれH,M,Sであれば、(H/24) + (M/1440) + (S/86400)という式で日単位の値が計算できます。
式で使っている24は１日の時間数、1440は１日の分数(24*60)、86400は１日の秒数(24*60*60)です。
例えば28:16:00 なら、　(28/24) + (16/1440) + (0/86400) = 1.177777778
３日と13:43:11 というように日数(D)が別に書かれるのであれば計算式は、D + (H/24) + (M/1440) + (S/86400) となります。

このように日を単位とする実数にすることで、１日を超える時間であってもグラフに正しく書くことができます。
グラフの軸が日単位になりますから、１日のところに「２４時」と軸の目盛りを書いてください。